# How can I load external images in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

JavaScript and I am loading random images from https://picsum.photos but it is not working. Note that for now, I do not want to use the new image optimization in next.js.
Local images are working but external images are not working.
Below is my code and my next.config.js

```
<Slider
            {...settingsThumbs}
            asNavFor={nav1}
            ref={slider => setSlider2(slider)}
          >
            {slidesData.map(slide => (
              <div className='slick-slide' key={slide.id}>
                <img
                  className='slick-slide-image'
                  src={`https://picsum.photos/800/400?img=${slide.id}`}
                  alt='sfd'
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </Slider>
```

below is my next.js config

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['https://picsum.photos/']
  }
};
```

Comment: What does `not working` mean? What does your network tab in the inspector tell you about the loading of the images? What does the rendered markup look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#domains), the domain does not appear to need a protocol (https or http) in front of it. Try

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['picsum.photos']
  }
};
```

I also suspect you have an error like the following in your console, going off [this source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/74b6389bd60505d3a2a8d902241e344b65356f1a/packages/next/next-server/server/config.ts#L417):

> domains value must follow format `{ domain: 'picsum.photos', ... }`.
> See more info here: [https://err.sh/next.js/invalid-i18n-config`](https://err.sh/next.js/invalid-i18n-config%60)

Note: Modifications to the `next.config.js` file may sometimes require to to restart the dev server before they take effect.